# Connect from eclipse to svn in intranet

Tags: svn, windows-7

I'm currently trying to connect to my TortoiseSVN that is running on a Windows7 machine with a given internal ip `192.168.178.22`. I'm trying to connect from my laptop via eclipse that is running Ubuntu 10.x. Unfortunately I can't get a connection and I have no idea, what the problem is. My svn-connector in eclipse is `SVNKit 1.3.5...`.
I have verified the IP by sending a ping to the Win7 machine. That works.  
  
Now the problem: I try to import the existing project from svn. Enter the URL `svn://192.168.178.22` and try to hit browse - nothing happens(the corresponding window opens, but everything is pending). The next step was trying to connect through console. So i opened a terminal and tried `svn checkout svn://192.168.178.22` and again - nothing happens(no output). Then I tried to disable the windows firewall - entering `svn checkout svn://192.168.178.22` again leads to `connection refused`.

And now I don't know what exactly the problem is. Why is the connection refused? I don't have username or password on the svn, the windows firewall is disabled.

Sorry, if this question is duplicate. I found some things in stackoverflow, but nothing seemed to be my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you can connect to that machine? Try ping 192.168.178.22 in the console

Comment: Yes, I have done that. It works.

Comment: TortoiseSVN is an SVN client, not an SVN server. Connecting to TortoiseSVN from another SVN client doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JB Nizet pointed out, I tried to connect from one SVN client to another. This can't work.
Thanks for the hint.